# App crashes when start a new intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Its been a while since I made an app. So I may be forgetting something. Whenever I press a button to start another intent, the app crashes. Is there something I'm missing?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent play = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PointsActivity.class);
                startActivity(play);
            }
        });

        Button leaderButton = findViewById(R.id.leader_board);
        leaderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent leader = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LeaderBoard.class);
                startActivity(leader);
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace so we can see what is going on

Comment: Without any stacktrace nor additional code its hard to tell whats going on. Please update your question so we can help.

Comment: Did you declare activities in your manifest?

Comment: what is your man?

Comment: Try adding activity in manifest, this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Look like you are not declaring your next activity in AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<manifest ... >
  <application ... >
      <activity android:name=".PointsActivity" />
      <activity android:name=".LeaderBoard" />
      ...
  </application ... >
  ...
</manifest >
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your stacktrace it is impossible to know what your error is, are you getting invalid casting exceptions? Usually you need to cast widgets into objects before assigning them to variables Ie your line

`Button playButton = findViewById(R.id.playbutton);`

should be

`Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);`

notice the explicit cast to `Button`, you may be getting errors like `cannot cast android.widget.button to button`, this will fix those.